# Creating menu from Text

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP programming and dont know the exact syntax of various labrary functions like , split, find ,etc.
I am having following text with me
in a string variable

```
$menu = '/home-page|HOME
/our-iphone-app|OUR iPhone APP
/join-us|JOIN ME
/contact-us|CONTACT US';
```

I want to populate to arrays with this text one array containing the portion before the pipe | and second array contains portions after pipe. How to do this using some split by `char(|)` method.

Finally arrays must contain

```
$arraypage = {'0'->'/home-page','1'->'/our-iphone-app'} // etc, and...
$arrayTitle = {'0'->'HOME','2'->'OUR iPhone App'} // etc
```

Comment: You really want that `$arrayTitle = {'0'->'HOME','2'->'OUR iPhone App'}`, not `$arrayTitle = {'0'->'HOME','1'->'OUR iPhone App'}` ?

Comment: Hmm. I'd personally suggest you to use another syntax when declaring the menu. Why would you write an overly complicated string, dissect it into arrays and then put together the page, when you could also put together a multidimensional array, like: `$menu = array(array("home", "/link-to-home"), array("contact us", "/contact-us"));` and then access the entries directly. Just a matter of preference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break up the string by new lines and then by pipe characters.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $menu);
$arraypage = array();
$arrayTitle = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($arraypage[], $arrayTitle[]) = explode('|', $line);
}
```

var_dump of the resulting arrays gives:

```
array
  0 => string '/home-page' (length=10)
  1 => string '/our-iphone-app' (length=15)
  2 => string '/join-us' (length=8)
  3 => string '/contact-us' (length=11)

array
  0 => string 'HOME' (length=4)
  1 => string 'OUR iPhone APP' (length=14)
  2 => string 'JOIN ME' (length=7)
  3 => string 'CONTACT US' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode("\n", $array);
$result1 = array();
$resutl2 = array();

foreach($array as $arr){
    $temp = explode('|', $arr);
    $result1[] = $temp[0];
    $result2[] = $temp[1];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you make your string contain another separator like so:

```
$menu = '/home-page|HOME:/our-iphone-app|OUR iPhone APP:/join-us|JOIN ME:/contact-us|CONTACT US';
```

Then you can use the explode method to split up your string to an associative array.

```
$array = explode(":", $menu);
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
     $array[$key] = explode("|", $val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just define the data in an array to start with, rather than as a string. I'd also build it in the format

```
$menu_array = {
  {'url'=>'/home-page','text'=>'HOME'},
  {'url'=>'/our-iphone-app','text'=>'OUR iPhone APP'},
  {'url'=>'/join-us','text'=>'JOIN ME'},
  {'url'=>'/contact-us','text'=>'CONTACT US'},
};
```

Since that's almost certainly going to be more useful for whatever you do with it next.

If you do need to use a string for some reason though, I'd say a regular expression is the tidiest way to do this. The following:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?P<url>[^|]+)\\|(?P<text>\\V+)\\v*$/m',$menu,$menu_array,PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

would set $menu_array to the format I used above.
In fairness, using a regular expression for this may be a little overkill, but I prefer the power of regexes, which are easier to tweak later when you want to add things than loops of explode()s.